# CSS Animation on SVG not working

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm new to using svg code. I'm trying to animate one with css and I'm also using bourbon. Nothing is happening and I can't figure out why. Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

It's not working in firefox or in webkit (chrome)

Thanks :

```
 <body>
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 200 200"> 
  <g id="chemistry">
    <g id="bubbles">
        <circle id="bubble1" class="liquid" cx="54.2" cy="141.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble2" class="liquid" cx="65.2" cy="139.4" r="8"/>
            <circle id="bubble3" class="liquid" cx="77.2" cy="138.4" r="8"/>
            <circle id="bubble4" class="liquid" cx="86.2" cy="140.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble5" class="liquid" cx="97.2" cy="135.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble6" class="liquid" cx="108.2" cy="138.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble7" class="liquid" cx="117.2" cy="134.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble8" class="liquid" cx="127.2" cy="137.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble9" class="liquid" cx="136.2" cy="134.4" r="8"/>
        <circle id="bubble10" class="liquid" cx="146.2" cy="136.4" r="8"/>
     </g>
      <g id="liquid">
          <polygon class="liquid" points="176.3,181.6 22.1,180 46,139.9 147,135.7"/>
      </g>
      <g id="bottle">
          <path class="bottle" d="M188.5,171.2c4.8,7.6,5.7,14.1,2.7,19.5c-2.9,5.4-8.9,8.1-     17.9,8.1h-147c-9,0-15-2.7-17.9-8.1
            c-2.9-5.4-2-11.9,2.7-19.5L75.3,70V19.1h-8.2c-2.2,0-4.1-0.8-5.7-2.4c-1.6-1.6-2.4-3.5-2.4-5.7c0-2.2,0.8-4.1,2.4-5.7
            c1.6-1.6,3.5-2.4,5.7-2.4h65.3c2.2,0,4.1,0.8,5.7,2.4c1.6,1.6,2.4,3.5,2.4,5.7c0,2.2-0.8,4.1-2.4,5.7c-1.6,1.6-3.5,2.4-5.7,2.4
            h-8.2V70L188.5,171.2z M89,78.7L26,178.2l71.9-0.6l74.8,0.9l-62.2-99.8l-2.6-4V70V19.1H91.6V70v4.7L89,78.7z"/>
      </g>
       </g>
    </svg>
 </body>
```

CSS w/ Bourbon:

```
body {
  background: #3b3b3d;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

@include keyframes (scale) {

  0% {
   @include transform(scale(1));
  }

  25% {
    @include transform(scale(1.75));
  }

  50% {
     @include transform(scale(0.5));
  }

  75% {
    @include transform(scale(1.25));
  }

  100% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
  }
}

#chemistry {
  @include animation(scale 3.0s ease-in infinite);  
}

.bottle {
  fill: #2BAAD6;
}

.liquid {
  fill: #D960EA;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can `include` like that. As I understand it you require a different keyframe declaration for each vendor prefix at the moment. **What is the output CSS?**. Also `scale` may be a keyword not available for an animation name...(not sure on that one).

Comment: Can you setup your project in http://jsfiddle.net/ and provide a link?

Comment: You can include like that using Bourbon. It just basically prefixes the elements.

Comment: Try calling the transform on the SVG instead of the group.

Comment: Still need to see a Fiddle with output CSS

Comment: Sorry - My email notifications were not working.
Here is the code on codepen: http://codepen.io/MandyMadeThis/pen/CuwsA

I tried the transform on the SVG first and also didn't work.

Comment: Tried changing the animation name from scale to chemistry - still nothing...

Comment: This codepen is working?

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/km4u9/ for a jsfiddle that uses a manual step for doing the bourbon transform with http://sassmeister.com/ I'm getting the bubbles moving, but not perhaps in the intended manner.

Comment: It's only working in Safari thesublimeobject - wondering why I can't get it to work in Chrome or firefox?

Comment: When I view the codepen.io that you linked with Chrome and Firefox I'm seeing the flask changing scale. Maybe we need to clarify what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Using the following bourbon and running it through sassmeister:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
body {
  background: #3b3b3d;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

@include keyframes (scale) {

  0% {
   @include transform-origin(center center);
   @include transform(translateY(50px));
   @include transform(scale(1));
  }

  25% {
    @include transform(scale(1.75));
  }

  50% {
     @include transform(scale(0.5));
  }

  75% {
    @include transform(scale(1.25));
  }

  100% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
  }
}

#bubbles .liquid {
  @include animation(scale 3.0s ease-in infinite);  
}

.bottle {
  fill: #2BAAD6;
}

.liquid {
  fill: #D960EA;
}
```

Yields: http://jsfiddle.net/km4u9/2/ Where the bubbles animate in the flask. Adjust the animation values to tweak the effect to your desired outcome. I did include some spaces in the `<path>` element in the svg.

Comment: Thanks Jason - that's what I was going to do once I got it working. I can still only see that animation and the scaling one that I made in safari. I'm on a mac and I'm just seeing a static image on both chrome and firefox. So strange.

Comment: Which version of chrome and firefox are you using? I was testing with a windows machine and the latest chrome and firefox.

Comment: Firefox & Chrome both auto update themselves. Chrome = 33.0.1750.146 Firefox = 27.0.1. Well at least I've narrowed it down to being a mac only issue. Thanks again